# Fancybox: URL to raw image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

it is possible to show a link to the raw image in popup window of Fancybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this here: http://photocontest.highpoint.edu/

I had to hack/customize Fancybox to achieve this.

The biggest problem I had was that Fancybox creates clickable areas to go to the next/previous images.  These clickable areas take 100% of vertical space.  That means you couldn't click on links below FancyBox.  It took a bit of jQuery to manipulate CSS to work around that.

This is my javascript function to fix Fancybox CSS:

```
function fix_fancybox_css() {
  if ($("div#fancybox-content a").length>0) {
    $("#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right").css({
      'height':Math.floor($("div#fancybox-content a:visible").position().top)+'px',
      'top':'0px',
      'bottom':''
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to display the URL along with the image in a popup window. I haven't used Fancybox myself but there is a similar jQuery lightbox clone called [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) which is very simple to use. You can add your own content (URL in your case) as a description for the image which appears just below the image in the popup. You can check out a demo on its website.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Check out the [inline examples](http://fancybox.net/home) on fancybox.net.  They're just HTML.